".aus" to ".wav" convert Tools after convert Sound Problem
I'm trying to make a small application to convert ".aus" audio extension files to “.wav" in Python. But after converting, a part of the sound in ".wav" is distorted, and I can't find the reason for this. I'm new to coding, can anyone help me? I'm getting suspicious of these codes
""
Extract audio data (after track data)
    raw_audio_data = aus_data[audio_data_start:]

    # Audio parameters
    frame_rate = 44100 # This and other parameters may vary depending on the .aus file
    sample_width = 2 # 2 bytes = 16 bit audio
    channels = 2 # Stereo sound

    # check the length of raw audio data
    raw_audio_length = len(raw_audio_data)

    # Set the length of the audio data divided by the sample width multiplied by the number of channels
    adjusted_length = raw_audio_length - (raw_audio_length % (sample_width * channels))
    raw_audio_data = raw_audio_data[:adjusted_length]

    # raw audio data -> pydub AudioSegment object
    audio_segment = AudioSegment(
        raw_audio_data,
        frame_rate=frame_rate,
        sample_width=sample_width,
        channels=channels
    )


Is there a spec for the .aus format?

Yamaha audio style (.aus)
